# Returning a tuple of multipe objects in Python C API

Tags: python, return, tuples, python-c-api

I am writing a native function that will return multiple Python objects

```
PyObject *V = PyList_New(0);
PyObject *E = PyList_New(0);
PyObject *F = PyList_New(0);

return Py_BuildValue("ooo", V, E, F);
```

This compiles fine, however, when I call it from a Python program, I get an error:

> SystemError: bad format char passed to Py_BuildValue

How can this be done correctly?

EDIT:
The following works

```
PyObject *rslt = PyTuple_New(3);
PyTuple_SetItem(rslt, 0, V);
PyTuple_SetItem(rslt, 1, E);
PyTuple_SetItem(rslt, 2, F);
return rslt;
```

However, isn't there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: You also need to remember to decrement the reference count on V, E and F (`Py_DECREF(V);`, etc.) after calling `Py_BuildValue`, since `Py_BuildValue` increments the reference count of any object used with the `O` format specifier (see http://docs.python.org/c-api/arg.html#Py_BuildValue).  Otherwise, the lists will never be freed, and you have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am returning `Py_BuildValue("NNN", V, E, F)` which does not increment the reference count.

Comment: I have a question when will V,E,F be free (equivalent Py_DECREF) after return to Python implementation? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it wants upper-case O?  `"OOO"`, not `"ooo"`.

Comment: Maybe you have also to add parenthesis to make python understand that you want to build a tuple :
    return Py_BuildValue("(OOO)", V, E, F);

Answer (score 2):

As Ned Batcheder noted Py_BuildValue requires Uppercase and paranthesis to create the Tuple

```c
Py_BuildValue("(OOO)", V, E, F);
```

Another option to achieve the same results is `PyTuple_Pack`

```c
PyTuple_Pack(3, V, E, F);
```

Answer (score -6):

Use [Cython](http://www.cython.org/).

```
return V, E, F
```